# Why do I get "403 Forbidden" when I connect to whatismyip.com?

Tags: delphi

With the following code, I get exception class EIdHTTPProtocolException with message 'HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden'. Process svchostip.exe (11172)

```
function GetInternetIP:string;
var
  IdHTTPMainUrl : TIdHTTP;
begin
  try
    IdHTTPMainUrl := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
    IdHTTPMainUrl.Request.Host := 'http://www.whatismyip.com/automation/n09230945.asp';
    Result := idHTTPMainUrl.Get('http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp');
  except
    IdHTTPMainUrl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It's kind of lucky, otherwise TIdHTTP would leak.

Comment: You're setting the `Host` property to something that obviously isn't a host name. It's not supposed to be an entire URL. You're connecting to *automation.whatismyip.com*, so use that for the `Host` property, too.

Comment: You are not even supposed to be assigning the `Request.Host` maually at all. `TIdHTTP` manages that value internally.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to set your user agent, this is documented in WhatIsMyIP [faq](http://www.whatismyip.com/faq/automation.asp):

> •Please set your program's user agent to Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
>   WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0 , this will keep your
>   program from being blocked by CloudFlare

Also freeing the `TIdHTTP` instance should be unconditional, you're only freeing it when an exception is thrown. Use exception handling, well, to handle exceptions.

```
function GetInternetIP:string;
var
  IdHTTPMainUrl : TIdHTTP;
begin
  IdHTTPMainUrl := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    IdHTTPMainUrl.Request.UserAgent :=
      'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:12.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/12.0';
    Result := idHTTPMainUrl.Get('http://automation.whatismyip.com/n09230945.asp');
  finally
    IdHTTPMainUrl.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I got the same problem after your Solution the new error is 503 Service temporaly unaivable... How to fixx?

Comment: @Poly - I don't know but they may have changed their rules. Visit [this link](http://www.whatismyip.com/ip-faq/automation-rules/) which links to [this one](http://www.whatismyip.com/membership-options/). Maybe they require an account..

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I keep forgetting that I have to do this when I use Indy's get function(). Bookmarked it this time.